# Try to understand back end and frontend

Tags: javascript, python, frontend, backend

I learn to code in python and Java in the same time, but can someone provide clear instruction for when you develop app to playstore,

Like python is Backend for Instagram, but what the front end, I mean the design, colors,

For web apps is html/css/bootstrap and Javascript.

I just get littel bit confused after researching it, about mobile apps, there are also other big apps use python as back end, but for front end?
Kivy people say it bad and the design is not the best, then flask and Django....

Can someone explain and save time to me and other people,

Like Backend is python and front end is? For mobile apps and what bad and good

Thanks

Coders with years of experience should able to understand my confusion,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a coder with years of experience but I'll try my best to answer.
So basically the way I think about it is the difference is where the code is executed.

Front end code is executed on the browser or on the users computer. Things like the GUI and the way everything is arranged and presented to the user.

Back end code is run on a server that is physically located in a different location. Examples include SQL database information, game hosting for online gaming, bank details for bank transactions.
Typically the back end code is not visible to the user for security and performance reasons.

Like you said, Python and Java can be used for both frond and back end, where they would separate is when you create a different program for each.
I.e. a server program for server processing - back end
and a client program for user interactions and sending instructions to the back end.

Hopefully that makes sense. First time posting and as I said I'm not the most experienced but that is how I understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let me break it down.

An app is usually broken down between 3 separate "sides". The Front-end, The Back-end and the API.

## The Front-End

The Front-End is what you as the user see, it's stuff like UI design, Layout, and for websites, the HTML + CSS.

## The Back-end

This is the brain of the operation. This is the Algorithm, The Server with the Images, the AI, the everything else basically.

## The API

This is the glue to hold the front-end and back-end together, and often, is used to get data from multiple back-end servers into one front-end product.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be entirely correct, but here it is simply. The frontend is everything the user sees, such as the GUI and all that stuff. The backend is everything that happens in the background, such as the server and how data is transferred between the user and the server. When it comes to most programming languages, they are equipped with tools that make them able to do both frontend and backend development. For example, for python, there is Django(backend) and PyQT(frontend).

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is developing rest(or any other) api,
this part should be written with python or java or any other server side language,
in a general scenario interactions that need to be handled by a server that is running your code and giving back the results and only results to the user or things like databases, maybe saving a file on a hard disk etc,,
why? because some interactions need to be out of the reach of users,any code that is running on a browser for example can be modified by anyone running that code,so if for example you need to register some data to a database, it's not wise to do it in javascript that is running in client browser,because for storing data you need to give access to database for any code that is going to do the job, so if you do that user can see and use that access (maybe a username and password for db) hoewer he likes, database needs a username and password for example and we provided it in our html/js,user can see and modify all of html/js.so no let us store our username and password in a python function on a secure server and connect to that funtion with an api endpoint for example and then this function will login to database and bring back or store what ever we want, and after that gives you a success or fail etc.. response.  so you can determine if this job was succesfull or not and maybe why not, this is just an example that is used for very general usages like a user Authentication, think about how users of a website or app can login with email and password, we need a db that stores the information of all users, user should provide email and pass via a html form for example, javascript can be used to deliver these two property to a certain api endpoint that you created with for example python or any of it's web framworks like django so we can check if in fact there is a user with this email and password in out users database,if it was or python function should return for example a success message and not somthing else,
here our python/django is the backend (the code that a server runs and not client,not google chrome or somthing alike)
the html/js is the frontend or client, (code that is running by user device phone pc or any other device)
usually we consider database as part of backend stack because it's most likly only is getting used by backend code,
any other operation that needs to be on server is part of backend wether it's because of security or any other reason,
any code on users device is the frontend wether is an app on android/Ios or web-browser
I tried to be clear but my limited english didn't really helped.hopefully I was helpful if not there are many more people that are able to explain these concepts much better.